# Formula to add a month to the next cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I think this will be a simple one. I am creating a work rota and need to find a formula. To make it easier to answer, I have included a screenshot below for what I need for my work rota.

when I enter the date 1/1/19 (1st Jan) in cell b1, I want the next cell (c1) to automatically be 1/2/19 (1st Feb).

Thank you

[image: Image example]

Comment: And when it is `31/1/2019`, what should the output be?

Comment: my question was, is the format dd-mm-yyy or mm-dd-yy?  In other words are you increasing by 1 day or by 1 month?

Comment: It is part of a much larger project that I have excluded to make it easier to answer. 

It will only ever need to add a month to the first box. 
I will type 1/1 in box one, the next box needs to add a month so it is 1/2. 

It will never be another date.

Comment: 1 month - thank you

Comment: Then `=EOMONTH(A1,0)+1`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Hey! Congratulations on your SO 100K; sorry I missed the party.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott Craner suggested in a comment, you can do this with:

```
=EOMONTH(B1,0)+1
```

EOMONTH returns the last day of the month that is a specified number of months before or after the month of the referenced date.  In your example the date in B1 is in January 2019.  A month difference of `0` means you're referring to that same month.  EOMONTH will then return January 31, 2019, the last day of that month.  Dates are stored as day counts, so adding `1` is adding one day, putting you at February 1, 2019.

It isn't clear from the question whether input dates will always be the first day of a month.  If you could input another day of the month, and you want the result to be the same day of the month in the next month, we need to tweak the formula a little.

Note that you will need to consider how to handle the different day counts per month.  If the input date is January 31, 2019, what day would you want as a result for the next month?  Dealing with that should really be the subject of another question if it applies.

A way to handle the basics using Excel's default rules could be this:

```
=EOMONTH(B1,0)+DAY(B1)
```

DAY extracts the day of the month from a date.

If this result displays as a raw day count (internal date storage format), just apply the date format you want.